# How to add file into Appx directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8.1

I've 2 folders visible in Solution Explorer in my project (sample grid app):

`fasdalocation` and `fasadalocation2`.

`fasadalocation` was previously oryginal `DataModel` folder in `sample grid app`, `fasadalocation2` is folder created by me.

Two folders contain identical file: `SampleData.json`.

I can acces to json file from `fasadalocation` by

```
    Uri("ms-appx:///fasadalocation/SampleData.json")
```

unfortunatelly this don't work for `fasadalocation2` (I got `FileNotFoundException`).

It's caused by fact that
`C:\Users\Jakub\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\sample grid app\sample grid app\bin\Debug\AppX`
location doesn't contain `fasadalocation2`.

How can I add `fasadalocation2` into appx?

Of course I thought that simple insertion folder into AppX location isn't a gentle solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the 2 files are content files that need to be deployed to your output folder and one of them does not have the correct build action to copy it to the folder.

Right click on SampleData.json in the fasadalocation2 folder and ensure it's build action is set to `Content` and `CopyAlways`.